# Problem with inet address that shows local ip

Tags: ip

recently i installed Ubuntu to my computer, and I'm facing a problem that i can't find answer in Google, when i write ifconfig in the terminal it shows my inet ip address as 10.0.0.15 instead of a normal ip address 
[look here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/igAzN.png)

```
wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 3c:a0:67:35:9e:ee  
      inet addr:10.0.0.15  Bcast:10.0.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::3ea0:67ff:fe35:9eee/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:690847 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:393241 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:970697260 (970.6 MB)  TX bytes:39743835 (39.7 MB)
```

Comment: Please copy-and-paste text instead of linking to screenshots. What makes you believe the IP address is incorrect?

Comment: Edited, because an ipv4 address should appear without the 0.0 in the middle,  right?

Comment: Not necessarily, what are the IP addresses for other devices on the same network; phones, iPads, Windows computers, etc.?

Comment: on my phone, the ip address is 10.0.0.2 but that's the local ip, im searching for my external ip on the computer @chili555

Comment: 10.0.0.15 seems normal for a small private LAN connected to the public internet by a router. On most small networks, your computer only knows the LAN IP it is assigned by the router (or equivalent). Everything on the LAN side of the router *shares* the same public IP address. To learn the public IP address, you must ask the router or an external site. Why is the IP address important? Is there a problem?

Comment: Please check: http://www.whatismyip.org

Comment: Your readings above look perfectly normal. Is there some other problem that you are trying to solve?